# How to add serial numbers in words depending upon the output?

Tags: python

```
def Pythagorean_Triplets(N) :
    c = 4 
    m = 2
    while c < N :
        for n in range(1, m) :
            a = m * m - n * n
            b = 2 * m * n
            c = m * m + n * n
            if c > N :
                break    
            print([a, b, c])    
        m = m + 1
N = int(input("\nEnter the value of N uptil which you want to get the Pythagorean Triplets: "))
print(f"\nPythagorean Triplets uptil {N} are: ")
Pythagorean_Triplets(N)
```

## Output as per my code

```
Enter the value of N uptil which you want to get the Pythagorean Triplets: 20

Pythagorean Triplets uptil 20 are: 
[3, 4, 5]
[8, 6, 10]
[5, 12, 13]
[15, 8, 17]
[12, 16, 20]
```

How to get an output in the below-mentioned format, with serial numbers in words for every list of output?

## Required Output

```
Enter the value of N uptil which you want to get the Pythagorean Triplets: 20

Pythagorean Triplets uptil 20 are: 
First list  :  [3, 4, 5]
Second list :  [8, 6, 10]
Third list  :  [5, 12, 13]
Fourth list :  [15, 8, 17]
Fifth list  :  [12, 16, 20]
```

and so on depending upon output.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to use [num2words](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/) library to convert int to word and get the output you desire.

```
pip install num2words
```

You need to integrate a counter into your code that carries forward the number of iterations and a capitalize to have the first letter capitalized.

So, you have to integrate it in your code like this:

```py
from num2words import num2words


def Pythagorean_Triplets(N):
    c = 4
    m = 2
    curr_iter = 1
    while c < N:
        for n in range(1, m):
            a = m * m - n * n
            b = 2 * m * n
            c = m * m + n * n
            if c > N:
                break
            serial_num_word = num2words(curr_iter, ordinal=True).capitalize()
            print(f"{serial_num_word} list : {[a, b, c]}")
            curr_iter +=1
        m = m + 1


N = int(input("\nEnter the value of N uptil which you want to get the Pythagorean Triplets: "))
print(f"\nPythagorean Triplets uptil {N} are: ")
Pythagorean_Triplets(N)
```

For N = 20, output will be:

```
Enter the value of N uptil which you want to get the Pythagorean Triplets: 20

Pythagorean Triplets uptil 20 are: 
First list : [3, 4, 5]
Second list : [8, 6, 10]
Third list : [5, 12, 13]
Fourth list : [15, 8, 17]
Fifth list : [12, 16, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting into `First` and `Second` wouldn't be a recommended method since it is nothing but some hard work. You could rather convert it into `ordinals`.

Here's a function (thanks to Winston Ewert's [post on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/41301)):

```
SUFFIXES = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}
def ordinal(num):
    # I'm checking for 10-20 because those are the digits that
    # don't follow the normal counting scheme. 
    if 10 <= num % 100 <= 20:
        suffix = 'th'
    else:
        # the second parameter is a default.
        suffix = SUFFIXES.get(num % 10, 'th')
    return str(num) + suffix
```

Here's an amendment to your code:

```
def Pythagorean_Triplets(N) :
    count = 0 # New variable count
    c = 4 
    m = 2
    while c < N :
        for n in range(1, m) :
            a = m**2 - n**2 #m * m is same as m*82 (same for n)
            b = 2 * m * n
            c = m**2 + n**2
            if c > N :
                break    
            count += 1 # Increment count on every print
            print(f"{ordinal(count)} list : {[a, b, c]}")  # f-strings for optimization   
        m += 1 # Optimization
N = int(input("\nEnter the value of N uptil which you want to get the Pythagorean Triplets: "))
print(f"\nPythagorean Triplets uptil {N} are: ")
Pythagorean_Triplets(N)
```

The whole thing looks like this:

```
SUFFIXES = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}
def ordinal(num):
    # I'm checking for 10-20 because those are the digits that
    # don't follow the normal counting scheme. 
    if 10 <= num % 100 <= 20:
        suffix = 'th'
    else:
        # the second parameter is a default.
        suffix = SUFFIXES.get(num % 10, 'th')
    return str(num) + suffix

def Pythagorean_Triplets(N) :
    count = 0 # New variable count
    c = 4 
    m = 2
    while c < N :
        for n in range(1, m) :
            a = m**2 - n**2 #m * m is same as m*82 (same for n)
            b = 2 * m * n
            c = m**2 + n**2
            if c > N :
                break    
            count += 1 # Increment count on every print
            print(f"{ordinal(count)} list : {[a, b, c]}")  # f-strings for optimization   
        m += 1 # Optimization
N = int(input("\nEnter the value of N uptil which you want to get the Pythagorean Triplets: "))
print(f"\nPythagorean Triplets uptil {N} are: ")
Pythagorean_Triplets(N)
```

You can learn more about [f-strings here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).